# Snowflake - How to split tuple of dates column while using in where clause

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, teradata

We have a scenario to apply on below table (sample provided) to split the date_clmn of varchar type to each individual.

```
tableA

emp_id  date_clmn
123     ("2021-01-01", "2021-03-03")
456     ("2021-02-01", "2021-04-03")
```

So, we have a scenario while inserting the data in the following table through dml operations.

```
For example1:

DELETE FROM tableA WHERE cast(BEGIN(date_clmn) as DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD') =current_date AND END(date_clmn) IS UNTIL_CHANGED ;
```

Which we need to convert to snowflake format, to take the first value and the second value from the date_clmn column **where we are considering the "date_clmn" is in varchar datatype**.

So, in snowflake we need to know how to get the first and second value from all rows when we are accessing the column in the filter clause ?

This is actually the teradata period datatype, which we want to equivalate in snowflake.

Comment: You better load the period into two seperate date columns. Otherwise use STRTOK plus CAST

Comment: You could also transform the varchar data into a VARIANT and modify it to be JSON.  This should be fairly straight-forward either on load to Snowflake or as a 1-time DML.  This would allow you to make reference to the end like `date_clmn:end` in your code.  Or maybe even as an ARRAY, which might work, as well.

Answer (score 0):

If there are always just 2 dates in there, easiest to me would be:

`to_date(split_part(column_1, ',', 1)) as date_1`
`to_date(split_part(column_1, ',', 2)) as date_2`

You might have to clean up the parentheses after with replace.

Answer (score 0):

Below is script which helps you to pull needed data:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html

**Setup Data:**

```
create or replace table splittable (a number, v varchar);


insert into splittable (a, v) values (456,  '("2021-02-01", "2021-04-03")');
```

[image]

**Output Query:**

```
select a, regexp_replace(value,'\\("|"|\\)') as value
    from splittable, lateral split_to_table(splittable.v, ',');
```

[image]